# Any way to DRY this FactoryGirl example?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have the following factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name 'Name'
    password 'password'
    email 'email@example.com'
  end
end
```

I have the following code in `before` block (I am creating all possible variations of `email`-`some_boolean_flag` pairs where email can take `''` and default value and some_boolean_flag can be false/nil or true):

```
FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: '', some_boolean_flag: false)
FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: '', some_boolean_flag: true)
FactoryGirl.create(:user, some_boolean_flag: nil)
FactoryGirl.create(:user, some_boolean_flag: true)
```

How can I DRY it? Is there any way in FactoryGirl to create a list of objects but with specific attributes being different and without repeating same line over and over? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name 'Name'
    password 'password'
    email 'email@example.com'

    factory :boolean_user
      some_boolean_flag true
    end
  end
end
```

Test

```
['', 'email@example.com'].each do |email|
  FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: email)
  FactoryGirl.create(:boolean_user, email: email)
end
```

A note here, I am purposefully going with restating the 'email@example.com' because I like my factories to be what's needed to pass validations. I don't like to depend on the contents of a factory for my test to pass. I will always specifically call the data I need.

Comment: Thanks for reminding about trait factory, I hoped there was some FactoryGirl mechanism to create list with different attributes though. As for restating email, I think it's not that often that factory gets changed from valid to invalid, they are mostly made valid I believe for default factories, so I would rather check failed specs out - chances of it to occur are low though - rather have extra code with excess data.